# Joint Distribution of Correlated Binomial and Negative Binomial Variables

Tags: probability, correlation, binomial-distribution, negative-binomial-distribution, joint-distribution

Let $x$ and $y$ be correlated negative binomial distributions, $x\sim~NB(p_1,n_1)$ and  $y\sim~NB(p_2,n_2)$ respectively with correlation  $\rho$. Can we derive their joint distribution analytically? Subsequently, can also we do so for 2 correlated binomial distributions?

Comment: Unless the $n_i$ are trivially small or the $p_i$ are edge cases, the answer is no, because there are many different ways in which two variables can be correlated.  If this question arises out of a statistical problem you face, then you might make more progress by describing the problem in enough detail to reveal more clearly *how* your variables might be correlated.

Comment: Thank you. I am explicitly modelling one variable given the other in order to derive the joint distribution. However, I wanted to make sure I am not missing a simpler way. I guess  in general one cannot derive a joint distribution from its marginal distributions even if the correlation between them and the type of joint distribution is known, right?

Comment: That's right.  To get a sense of the possibilities, investigate *copulas.*  These are mathematical objects describing associations among random variables *regardless of their marginal distributions.*  In short, then, you can take any two univariate distributions, choose *any* bivariate copula you please, and correlate those distributions *via* that copula.  When the distributions are discrete, many different copulas can yield the same bivariate distribution, but even then there's almost always a huge number of possibilities.